# onClick update to firebase database not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to update the `identity` value of the user with `onClick` method of the update button but it is not working and no value is being updated.

Here is my activity (I used the Query to get to the user unique ID):

```
public class Update extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText identity;
    DatabaseReference ref;
    Button update;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_check);

        update = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_update);
        identity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_identity);

        mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("uploads");

        String key = getIntent().getExtras().get("androidId").toString();
        final Query userQuery = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").orderByChild("androidId");
        userQuery.equalTo(key).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
            new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot foodSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        final String userUID = foodSnapshot.getKey();
                        ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(userUID);
                        identity.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("identity"));

                        update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                ref.child("identity").setValue("noo");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
            }
        );
    }
}
```

My database structure is like:

```
{
  "Users" : {
    "uid1" : {
      "name" : "Josh",
      "identity": "yes"
    },
    "uid2" : {
      "name" : "June",
      "identity": "no"
    }
  }
}
```

And there is no error showing in the logcat. What might be the problem here?

Comment: Can you post your firebase structure? Do you see any errors in logcat(ie: permission denied)?

Comment: @sbso, I have included the database structure. Please have a look.

Comment: From a quick glance, adding the userUID in the databaseSnapshot should fix it. I can look closer shortly.

Comment: Well, thanks, I've added the child in the databaseSnapshot after you've said but still doesn't fix it. `ref.child("identity").setValue("noo");`  @sbso

Comment: The problem is you're trying to read a node without going through the structure. For example, you need to read the childs of Users/uid and then you can get the identity.

Comment: You say you are "trying to update the identity value of the user". This means that you want to change the uid which is basically a node?

Comment: @AlexMamo, actually, I'm trying to update the `"identity": "yes"` or `"identity": "no"` value to `"identity": "noo"` on Button click.

Comment: @Hijibiji Of a single user or of all users under `Users` node?

Comment: @AlexMamo, no, of a single user that I get from the Query `userQuery`. From the previous activity, I send an androidId and from that androidId, I Query the UserId having that androidId. On button click, I'm intending to change the `indentity` value of that user.

Comment: In which `uid1` can be equal to `getIntent().getExtras().get("androidId").toString()`, right?

Comment: No, actually `getIntent().getExtras().get("androidId").toString()` is the `androidId`. The `uid1` comes from the query of that `androidId` that is here `final String userUID = foodSnapshot.getKey();` @AlexMamo

Comment: Add some log here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the `ref` you've used is not pointing exactly to the node you want to be updated. You can use this to do so:

```java
update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                            DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(uidYouWant);
                                rootRef.child("identity").setValue("noo");
                            }
                        });
```

Also to get the `uidYouWant` instead of using `query` you can go though all the nodes to get the one you want, using `orderByChild()` and `equalTo()` directly like this:

```java
ref.orderByChild("androidID").equalTo(key).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for(DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                           // do what you want to

                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```